# VB form - to allow user interaction to select data from SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, excel, vb.net, forms, interaction

I am new to VB, just got started not long ago, and I am happy to be making progress.

However, I am more new to VB forms when connects to SQL server and allows user to interact with it to query out whatever data they wants into excel.

It begins like this, I've already created a userform that has checkbox (> than, < than), a textbox (input a number), and 2 other checkbox (male, female) and a combobox (state). I also already have the data in the SQL Server database.

What I am trying to do and is still trying is to allow users to interact with the form by checking the checkboxes, making selection in the combobox and inputting a number in the textbox and click on a button to run the VB program to export the requested data into Excel (my challenge is - it can export it into an Excel file that has already been created and saved in a directory or to export it into a newly created Excel file that has not been save yet (kind of like a pop-up).

For example - a user checks > than, and enter number 25 (btw this is age), and checks female and in combobox selects NY and click on a button. The program should query out, in this case, female over 25 that lives in NY and export it into Excel as a pop-up or an excel file that is already saved in a directory. I have been doing some research on this but hasn't made much progress as I am new to forms, connection and extraction. My code below creates an Excel file in a directory and is trying to query out the data into the save Excel file. My query is below too. Please advise !

```
Imports System.IO
Imports excel = Microsoft.office.interop.Excel
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Module module1
    Dim myconnection As SqlConnection
    Dim mycommand As SqlCommand
    Sub main()
        Dim xlapp = New excel.application
        xlapp.visible = True
        Dim xlwb As excel.workbook
        Dim xlws As excel.worksheet
        Dim path As String = "C:\users\t\"
        Dim excel_name As String = "zp"

        xlwb = xlapp.workbooks.add()
        xlws = xlwb.sheets("sheet1")
        xlwb.saves(path & excel_name)
        xlapp.save()
        xlapp.quit()

        Using myconnection As New SqlConnection("data source =afe;initial catalog=zp;integrated securitytrue")
            myconnection.Open()
            Dim mycommand As New SqlCommand("insert into openrowset('Microsoft.ace.oledb.12.0','excel 12.0; database=zp:\c:users\dek\rep\zp.xlsx;','SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]') select * from mem_TBL", myconnection)
        End Using
    End Sub
End Module
```

this is my query base on user selection as example.

```
SELECT a.z, a.ad, a.ag, a.ret, a.tot, a.wgt
FROM mtbl a INNER JOIN zTBL b ON a.z = b.zp
WHERE a.age > 25 AND a.ad = "NY" AND a.ret ="female"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the approach I use when exporting to Excel: I create a template of the Excel file that I will generate and save it in a fixed folder. When I export to excel, I:

1. copy the template file to a temporary folder
2. open the temporary file,
3. add the data to the temporary file,
4. close it,
5. save it to the destination file
6. delete the temporary file

   ```
   Private Sub ExportToExcel()
   Using myconnection As New SqlClient.SqlConnection("data source=afe;initial catalog=zp;integrated securitytrue")
       myconnection.Open()
       Dim mycommand As New SqlClient.SqlCommand("SELECT a.z, a.ad, a.ag, a.ret, a.tot, a.wgt FROM mtbl a INNER JOIN zTBL b ON a.z = b.zp WHERE a.age > @age AND a.ad = @state AND a.ret = @gender", myconnection)
       mycommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@age", 25)
       mycommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@state", "NY")
       mycommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gender", "female")
       Dim dataset As New DataSet
       Dim adapter As New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(mycommand)
       adapter.Fill(dataset, "data")

       Dim xlapp = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
       xlapp.visible = True
       Dim xlwb As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook
       Dim xlws As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet
       Dim templatePath As String = "<path to template file>"
       Dim path As String = "C:\users\t\"
       Dim excel_name As String = "zp"
       Dim tempFIle As String = templatePath & "\NAME OF YOUR TEMPLATE FILE INCLUDING EXTENSION"

       xlwb = xlapp.Workbooks.Open(tempFIle)
       xlws = CType(xlwb.Worksheets("Sheet1"), Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)

       Dim rowIndex As Integer = 0
       For Each row As DataRow In dataset.Tables(0).Rows
           '   since you alrady have a template, 
           '   you already know the cell mapping of each column
           '   in your template file.
           '   Excel uses Row, Column to map cells and is 1-based
           rowIndex += 1
           xlapp.Cells(rowIndex, 1).Value = row("<name of column 1>")
           xlapp.Cells(rowIndex, 2).Value = row("<name of column 2>")
           xlapp.Cells(rowIndex, 3).Value = row("<name of column 3>")
           xlapp.Cells(rowIndex, 4).Value = row("<name of column 4>")
           '.
           '.
           'xlapp.Cells(rowIndex, N).Value = row("<name of column N>")
       Next

       xlapp.DisplayAlerts = False
       xlwb.SaveAs(path & excel_name)
       xlwb.Close()
       xlapp.DisplayAlerts = True
       System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlwb)

       xlapp.Quit()
       System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlapp)

       System.IO.File.Delete(tempFIle)
   End Using
   End Sub
   ```

Comment: Thank you for your code example. I understand your concept however I noticed there are a few missing pieces, some I could fill, others I can't. I don't want to write too long of a message, -the main problem for me is how do I reference the data in SQL Sever for a particular table(Col and rows for the query and looping it into excel). The second thing is how do I put the query of let's say in the where clause a.ad <>"i" or when a.ret = "".  Thanks again. I appreciate your code, just some breaks and a bit unclear but very nice concept and example.

Comment: It was my fault, I just noticed that when I put the creation of excel workbook before the using, the code runs but it never goes into the For Loop, now that I put it in between the using. The code runs into the For Loop, but I don't know how to access the query table in db as your example is row("<value at cell # 1>"). Thanks.

Comment: Just want to update that I got the row("<value at cell #1>") issue resolved by looking at this link, https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-us/f2e15d21-c1ad-47f3-9c55-1cdb8212af5b/vbnet-loop-throught-dataset-question?forum=vblanguage and specifically this code.  FoundRow("ColumnName").  Your example is good.